# polymer vulcanize keep external links

Tags: javascript, polymer, vulcanize

I am using Polymer to build widget in my web app,
since I need my web app works with Mozilla and IE I need vulcanize my widget/custom-tags in single file .html, then the polymer frameworks will be  include in my file .html. 
That's fine if I have one single page, but since I need to use Polymer in different web pages that force me to download the framework Polymer more than once.
There is a way to vulcanize the page and download Polymer just once? 
I mean without include the framework into the page but still using external link

thanks

michele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I explain in bad way myself,
My achievement is "download the framework Polymer just once" and not in any single web page of my website. the solution I have found is 
 - open the file polymer.html
 - copy the javascript code 
 - past in a new file ex. polymer.js
 - go to the web page which use polymer and change the tag  in

So that my web pages will download the framework Polymer just once

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is the `--exclude` flag:

```
vulcanize --exclude "path/to/target/subpath/" --exclude "path/to/target/subpath2/" target.html
```

It will do exactly what you are asking for.

https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize

Comment: that solution does not fit with my request since I need to let  my web pages which use with Polymer works  even in IE and  Mozilla which do not work with html import specs. I have figured out a possible solution in my own answer. thanks